rubyを実行できない
3か月ほど前にweb上のrubyの無料の講座を少しだけやり、また始めようと思い、初めて見ると前にファイルに保存されていたコードは実行できるのですが新しく書いたコードが実行できません。 No such file or directoryというエラーが出ているのですが以前つかえていたファイルに新しく書いたコードを保存しても実行できません。前に書いたコードを上書き保存で変更しても前の内容のものが実行されてしまいます。どうしたらいいか教えてください。
実行環境はWindows 11で講座のURLは https://www.javadrive.jp/ruby/#google_vignette です。
以前デスクトップ上に「rubyコード」という名前のフォルダを作り、その中にいくつか「sample〇.rb(〇の中は数字)」という名前でコードを保存していました。その一つがhello.rbという名前でputs"Hello,World!"というコードを書き、保存してコマンドプロントでruby hello.rbと書いて実行しました。それは以前も今も実行できます。しかし、puts"hello"と書いてhello.rbの名前を付けてrubyコードのファイルに上書き保存してコマンドプロントにruby hello.rbと打って実行するとHello,World!と出てきてしまいました。

どこで何をして、どんな状況で、何が失敗しているのか、を文章だけで正確に把握するには限界があります。他の人が状況を把握できるように、エラーが表示されている画面のウインドウ全体のスクリーンショットをそのまま貼り付けてみてください。

今回問題となっていたのは「フォルダパスの違い」なので、その情報が含まれている画像をそのまま削除してしまうと「何が問題だったのか」と「回答との整合が取れなくなる」ので、よい編集ではありません。隠したい情報があるなら、必要最低限の範囲をマスクするなり、ダミーの情報に置き換えた上で文字として追記し直すなどの対応を検討してください。

貼っていただいているスクショから想像で回答します。
コマンドプロンプトでRubyコマンドを打ち込む際のカレントディレクトリが間違えているのだと思います。
VSCodeのスクショを見る限り、hello.rbとsample6.rbファイルが保存されている場所は
C:¥Users¥"miyai yamato"¥"OneDrive - 信州大学"¥デスクトップ¥ruby
フォルダの中にあると思われます。
しかし、コマンドプロンプトのスクショを見ると、カレントディレクトリは
C:¥Users¥"miyai yamato"¥
になっています。
cdコマンドで
C:¥Users¥"miyai yamato"¥"OneDrive - 信州大学"¥デスクトップ¥ruby
まで移動してから同じように実行すれば実行できるのではないでしょうか？
hello.rbがNo such file or directoryにならないのはたまたま
C:¥Users¥"miyai yamato"¥
にhello.rbという同じファイル名のファイルが存在して、それを実行しているのではないでしょうか？
スクショからの憶測で回答しているため、間違えている可能性も大いにありますが、参考になれば幸いです。

解決できました！本当にありがとうございます！
